# IntelliJ 12: Showing Play 2.1 / Scala compile errors in Project navigator?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have IntelliJ 12 Ultimate and am using the Play Framework 2.1 with Scala (love them both)

One thing I miss from Eclipse is seeing my project files annotated with a red mark if they fail to compile.

I've tried enabling Preferences > Compiler > Use External Build > Make Project Automatically

This didn't show any errors (not even in the "Problems" panel)

I've tried the "Eclipse Mode" plugin. Also doesn't seem to have any effect. "No compilation problems found" in the Problems panel despite obvious issues with the code (renamed method to xxx without refactoring usages)

Suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and I simply solved it by making sure IntelliJ is not in power save mode because code analysis is disabled in that mode.

You can see if it's on or off thanks to the status bar on the bottom right of IntelliJ.

I hope for you it's as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Power save mode is turned off for me and I still can't get errors to be shown on the project file hierarchy unfortunately

Comment: @slm who was that comment directed at, please?